# How do I plot a Wind Rose in R?

Tags: r, openair

I want to plot a wind rose in R. I'm trying with the package "openair".
My database is in degrees/10 (within 0 and 36), if I plot this values (but it doesn't make sense), it works. But if i real degrees (degrees*10) it says:

Error in e2[[j]] : out of limits  (What is it?)

My code is:

```
windRose(meteo, ws = "Int Viento [Nudos]", wd = "Dir Viento", ws2 = NA, wd2 = NA, 
               ws.int = 3, angle = 3, type = "default", bias.corr = TRUE, cols= "default", 
              grid.line = NULL, width = 1, seg = NULL, auto.text= TRUE, 
              offset = 0, normalise = FALSE, max.freq =NULL, 
              paddle = FALSE, key.header = NULL, key.footer = "Nudos", 
               key.position = "bottom", key = TRUE, dig.lab = 5, statistic = "prop.count",
              pollutant = NULL, annotate = TRUE, border = NA)
```

I tried with the example database of Openair, and it works:

```
windRose(mydata, ws = "ws", wd = "wd", ws2 = NA, wd2 = NA, 
     ws.int = 2, angle = 30, type = "default", bias.corr = TRUE, cols
     = "default", grid.line = NULL, width = 1, seg = NULL, auto.text 
     = TRUE, breaks = 4, offset = 10, normalise = FALSE, max.freq = 
       NULL, paddle = TRUE, key.header = NULL, key.footer = "(m/s)", 
     key.position = "bottom", key = TRUE, dig.lab = 5, statistic = 
       "prop.count", pollutant = NULL, annotate = TRUE, angle.scale = 
       360, border = NA)
```

To compare both:

```
summary(mydata$wd)

 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  0     140     210     200     270     360     219 


summary(meteo$`Dir Viento`)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
0.0    90.0   140.0   175.5   270.0   360.0      43
```

Comment: Does it take 360, or does it only want values 0 --> 359? I'd check that.

Comment: Openair typically views 360 as North. So, it is likely something else...

Comment: If your are not going to supply data, there's only the opportunity for us to encourage you to learn to debug for yourself. Use `traceback()` and `options(error=recover)`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same (rather obscure) error when trying to make a windRose() of my own data, i.e.:

`Error in e2[[j]] : subscript out of bounds`

This error seems to occur when my winddirections (`wd`) are expressed exactly as multiples of 10 degree units between 0 and 360 degrees. In the help of the windRose() function I noticed the following for the `bias.corr` argument:

> `bias.corr`
>   When angle does not divide exactly into 360 a bias is introduced in the frequencies when the wind direction is already supplied rounded to the nearest 10 degrees, as is often the case. For example, if angle = 22.5, N, E, S, W will include 3 wind sectors and all other angles will be two. A bias correction can made to correct for this problem. A simple method according to Applequist (2012) is used to adjust the frequencies

By setting the argument `bias.corr=F` I managed to make the windRose without any errors, i.e.

`windRose(mydata, ws, wd, bias.corr=F)`

PS I use R 3.3.2 and openair 2.1-5